# How to go to account controller if 5 level of product hierarchy is defined in product controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have used attribute routing for creating a hierarchy like following.
**abc.com/Electronics/Audio/Portable Audio/iPods/Apple iPod Nano**

Last one is the name of the product. This is defined in product controller.

Now I want to go to account controller on register link click but I can't go there as any level of route is caught in above URL criteria and it always goes to product controller methods.

So my question is , how can I go to account controller on click of Register link click. The register link is defined in Layout.cshtml.

Thank You

Comment: I suspect that your route order might be the proble. Can you show us your routes?

Comment: [Route("{category}/{subcategory}/{subsubcategory}/{types}/{productname}")]
        public ActionResult ProductDetails(string category, string subcategory, string subsubcategory, string types,string productname)
        {
            productList = itemsRepo.getProductList(types);
            ViewBag.ProductSubcategory = types;
            return View("Types", productList);

        }

Comment: I don't have any specific route order defined. Just attribute routing(defined like above) and the default route which is by default there in routeconfig. Just added the line routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();   to enable attribute routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Just put the route before attribute routing. For example

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AccountRoute",
                url: "Account/Register",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Register"}
            );
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

And you can go to your desired controller. Can't believe it was that simple. I still think that there are more effective ways to do that.
Thanx mahlatse  & MisterJames

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you do set the order by virtue of the timing of your call, i.e. when you register the route attributes in relation to when you define the default route pattern. If you like, you can set the order of a `RouteAttribute` using the optional Order parameter.

`[Route("controller/action", Order = 1)]`

You may also wish to look at producing a `LocalRoute` that doesn't interfere with the default route routing, specifically for your complex product routing requirements:

- [Jon Galloway's walk through on custom constraints](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-asp-net-mvc-5-1-and-web-api-2-1-part-2-attribute-routing-with-custom-constraints).

Comment: I can't understand how to use ordering in this. Every controller method is called when corresponding link is clicked.